# Pass parameters to ExecuteSql()

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to pass a table name as a parameter to the `ExecuteSql()` method.

This is what I have tried:

```
        var viewName = "search_view";

        using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
        {
            db.ExecuteSql("REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW @viewName;", new { viewName });
        }
```

It doesn't work, it creates exception with the message of:

> Npgsql.PostgresException
>
> 42601: syntax error at or near "$1"

I enabled logging to try to see what SQL is generated but I think because of the exception the query isn't logged.

The query runs fine when it is all text, what am I doing wrong passing in the table name as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use DB parameters as a replacement for **parameters**, i.e. you can't use them as a free-text substitution for SQL template generation like you're trying to do.

You would need to use include the `viewName` in your SQL, e.g:

```
db.ExecuteSql($"REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW {viewName};");
```

Although if `viewName` was provided by the user you would need to guard it against possible SQL injection. My recommendation is checking against a white-list of allowed viewNames, e.g:

```
if (!AllowedViewNames.Contains(viewName))
    throw new Exception("Invalid View");
```

In OrmLite you can escape a string with `GetQuotedValue()` API, e.g:

```
var quotedViewName = db.GetDialectProvider().GetQuotedValue(viewName);
```

To detect invalid names for symbols like view names you can use a RegEx to only allow valid characters, e.g:

```
if (!new Regex(@"[^A-Za-z0-9_]").IsMatch(viewName))
    throw new Exception("Invalid View");
```

Whilst OrmLite's `SqlVerifyFragment()` extension method lets you detect potentially illegal SQL injection if you wanted to accept an SQL fragment, e.g:

```
db.ExecuteSql($"SELECT * FROM User WHERE {userSql.SqlVerifyFragment()}");
```

Where OrmLite will throw an `ArgumentException` if it detects a potential illegal SQL violation.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any public method available to strip sql injection attacks from strings?  In this case I am not taking user input for it but I am just curious to know for the future.

Comment: @Guerrilla See my updated answer for different ways to guard against SQL injection from user input.